# React : why the props changed?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to compare on the blur of a textarea if the value changed betwen the received props and the state. If yes , I trigger something, else I do nothing.

I initialized the state like that :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        question : this.props.question,
        loadingQuestionsWithAnswers : true,
        posting : false,
        error : '',
        disabled : !isAuthorized('FILL_ASF')
    }
}
```

My textarea is :

```
<textarea id={`answer_${key}`}
                                    placeholder = "A comment ..."
                                    value={(this.state.question && this.state.question.answer) || ""}
                                    onChange={event => this.handleAnswer(event.target.value)}
                                    onBlur = {() => this.handleBlurAnswer()}
                                />
```

I change the state in the "onChange" :

```
handleAnswer = (value) => {

    let question = this.state.question;
    question.answer = value;
    this.setState({
        question : question
    }, function(){
        console.log('this.props.question dans le handleAnswer', this.props.question.answer);
        console.log('this.state.question dans le handleAnswer', this.state.question.answer);
    })

}
```

And I do not understand why **this.props.question** has changed too (I see it in the console). I updated only the state.

I am a beginner in React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
question : this.props.question
```

You are assigning an *object reference* so both *state* and *props* reference the same *question* object.

You need to make a copy of the question object, and it depends if you want it to be deep or not.

shallow:

```
question: Object.assign({}, this.props.question)
```

deep:

```
question: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.question))
```

Comment: Thank cgTag. It works exactly like I expected. But sometimes, in some other components , I initialize the state with the props. Is it a wrong practice ? or not ?

Comment: It's not a good practice to hold the state in more than one position (single source of truth) IMHO